# How to apply function to each row of data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to calculate net present value (NPV) using `library(financial)` for each observation from given cashflow in `data.table` format.  Here is my cashflow:

```
library(data.table)    
dt <- data.table(id=c(1,2,3,4), Year1=c(NA, 30, 40, NA), Year2=c(20, 30, 20 ,70), Year3=c(60, 40, 0, 10))
```

To calculate NPV and update in data.table,

```
library(financial)
npv <- apply(dt, 1, function(x) cf(na.omit(x[-1]), i = 20)$tab[, 'NPV'])
dt[, NPV:=npv]
```

return,

```
   id Year1 Year2 Year3      NPV
1:  1    NA    20    60 70.00000
2:  2    30    30    40 82.77778
3:  3    40    20     0 56.66667
4:  4    NA    70    10 78.33333
```

How can I directly update result using function `cf` to each row in the `data.table` ?

FYI: In my real dataset, there are over 50 columns

Comment: Maybe `dt[, "NPV" := apply(dt, 1, function(x) cf(na.omit(x[-1]), i = 20)$tab[, 'NPV'])]` ?? Is this what you want?

Comment: or maybe `dt[, NPV := cf(na.omit(c(Year1, Year2, Year3)), i=20)$tab[, 'NPV'], by=1:nrow(dt)]`
`

Answer (score 1):

We can try a join based approach

```
dt[melt(dt, id.var = "id")[, .(NPV = cf(value[!is.na(value)], 
                      i = 20)$tab[, "NPV"]), id], on = 'id']
#   id Year1 Year2 Year3      NPV
#1:  1    NA    20    60 70.00000
#2:  2    30    30    40 82.77778
#3:  3    40    20     0 56.66667
#4:  4    NA    70    10 78.33333
```

Comment: Surprisingly it doesn't give that much of a speed advantage. The `cf` function in this context really needs a vectorized approach, otherwise it is always going to be run `nrow(dt)` times anyway.

Comment: @thelatemail  In that case a `for` loop with `set` could improve the speed.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the `cf` function to only calculate the part that is needed will speed things up *dramatically*:

```
dt[, NPV := {x <- na.omit(unlist(.SD)); sum(x * sppv(20,0:(length(x)-1)))}, by=id]

#   id Year1 Year2 Year3      NPV
#1:  1    NA    20    60 70.00000
#2:  2    30    30    40 82.77778
#3:  3    40    20     0 56.66667
#4:  4    NA    70    10 78.33333
```

In fact, this could probably be vectorised now.... hmmm, let me think!

Answer (score 0):

We could try and make our own `npv` function for using in this example.

```
dcf <- function(x, r, t0=FALSE){
  # calculates discounted cash flows (DCF) given cash flow and discount rate
  #
  # x - cash flows vector
  # r - vector or discount rates, in decimals. Single values will be recycled
  # t0 - cash flow starts in year 0, default is FALSE, i.e. discount rate in first period is zero.
  if(length(r)==1){
    r <- rep(r, length(x))
    if(t0==TRUE){r[1]<-0}
  }
  x/cumprod(1+r)
}

npv <- function(x, r, t0=FALSE){
  # calculates net present value (NPV) given cash flow and discount rate
  #
  # x - cash flows vector
  # r - discount rate, in decimals
  # t0 - cash flow starts in year 0, default is FALSE
  sum(dcf(x, r, t0))
}
```

Now, whenever you want to `apply(x,1,f)`, `melt`/`gather`/`nest` instead. 
Unless you are intending to totally mislead the users of your data, you should never drop `NA` when calculating NPV. This will mean that you are discounting cash flows to different points in time. Replace `NA` with 0 instead. I also see that the package you intended to use, discounts cash flows to year 0, basically meaning that the first cash flow (in Year1) is not discounted.

```
library(data.table)
npv_dt <- melt(dt, id.vars = "id")[is.na(value), value:=0][order(variable), .(NPV=npv(x=value, r=0.2, t0=TRUE)), by="id"]

setkey(dt, id)
setkey(npv_dt, id)

npv_dt[dt]

#>    id      NPV Year1 Year2 Year3
#> 1:  1 58.33333    NA    20    60
#> 2:  2 82.77778    30    30    40
#> 3:  3 56.66667    40    20     0
#> 4:  4 65.27778    NA    70    10
```